# Android TabHost not showing

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

Below is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="hk.teawood.httpwww.t_factory.stock_list"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

And here's the java file

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class stock_list extends TabActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stock_list);

        //iniControls();

        //loadList();
    }
}
```

I just put a TabHost to the layout, which the expected layout should be something like this:
[image]

But the result was, a blank activity was shown:
[image]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: If that's the exact code you're running, then all of your Views are empty and transparent.

Comment: @MikeM. Then how can I make the view non - transparent?? I am trying to add tab pages to the activity

Comment: Well, first of all, if you mean for the LinearLayouts to be your tabs, they should be inside of the `<TabWidget>` tags. Also, LinearLayouts are transparent by default. If you want colors, specify a `background` attribute for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this post:

https://gist.github.com/jerolimov/618086

And modified the code a bit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="hk.teawood.httpwww.t_factory.stock_list">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:tag="tab0"
                android:text="Lend Items" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:tag="tab0"
                android:text="Free Items" />
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListViewId2"
                android:layout_width="366dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListViewId"
                android:layout_width="366dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And it's working now!

[image]